# Finding $n$ for which $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a field.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a field for prime $n$. I am reading a proof of the first implication ($\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a field implies that $n$ is prime), and I don't think I understand it. It's only this direction I'm having trouble with, so I'm going to focus only on that. The proposed solution is:

> If $[a]$ has a multiplicative inverse $[b]$, $[ab] = [1]$; that is, $ab - 1$ is divisible by $n$. If $a$ were also a divisor of $n$, $ab - 1$ would also be divisible by $a$; so $1$ would be divisible by $a$; that is, $a = 1$. Then, if every nonzero element $[a]$ had an inverse, every positive divisor of $n$ less than $n$ would be $1$; then, $n$ would have exactly two positive divisors, $n$ and $1$ (because $n \geq 2$); that is, $n$ is prime.

There seem to be some jumps in this proof. First, the deduction that $n$ is prime almost surely has to follow from the assumption that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is in fact a field. So, assuming $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a field, every non-zero element has a multiplicative inverse, so for every $[a] \neq [0]$, there is a $[b]$ satisfying $[a][b] = [1]$. So, we need only show that any positive divisor of $n$ not equal to $n$ is $1$. So let $a$ be such a divisor, and consider $[a]$. Following this analysis, there is a $[b]$ satisfying $[a][b] = [1]$. So $[ab] = [1]$, so $n \mid ab - 1$. We supposed that $a$ is a divisor of $n$, and $n \mid ab - 1$, so $a \mid ab - 1$. So there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ak = ab - 1$. So $1 = ab - ak = a(b-k)$, so $a \mid 1$. The only positive divisor of $1$ is $1$, so $a = 1$. As $n$ has only two positive divisors, $1$ and $n$, it is prime.

Have I correctly interpreted this proof? Is the above reasoning correct?

Comment: You simply need to observe that if $n=ab$ is not prime, then $0=[a]\cdot [b]$. The product of two nonzero elements cannot be $0$ in a field.

Comment: Following up to this comment, the Wikipedia pages on the integers gives a decent write-up.

Comment: I understand this comment about zero divisors, but I'm primarily interested in knowing whether I've understood this particular proof.

Comment: From $a | ab - 1$, one immediately obtains $a|1$ (by just doing the division).

Comment: Your restatement of the proof seems correct to me. Often, published proofs skip steps, and assume the reader can find the (perceived as essentially trivial) intervening logic. As you increase in mathematical maturity, your perception of triviality will align with the writers more and more.

Comment: Your re-statement is correct; the step from the fact that $a$ divides $ab-1$ to concluding that $a$ divides $1$ is perhaps a bit too onerous: in general, we know that if $k$ divides both $x$ and $y$, then it divdes $x+y$ and $x-y$. Since $a$ clearly divides $ab$, if it also divides $ab-1$ then $a$ will divide $ab-(ab-1)=1$.